# Text encroaching on Padding of a parent div

Tags: html, css, styled-components

css isn't really my thing, so I'm having trouble formatting my text in my div. I'm making a portfolio, and I have a card with a title and a description.

however the size of the card has paddings, and the description text is invading this padding.

[image: print with problem.]

code of my card.

```
export const CardContainer = styled.div`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme["base-post"]};
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 15rem;
`

export const CardContent = styled.div`
  padding: 2rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;
  position: sticky ;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1.5rem;
`
export const CardTitle = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  h1{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: ${(props) => props.theme["base-title"]};
  }

  span{
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    color: ${(props) => props.theme["base-span"]};
  }
`
export const CardDescription = styled.p`
  font-family: 'jetBrains Mono', 'sansSerif';
`
```

```html
export function Card() {
  return(
    <CardContainer>
      <CardContent>
        <CardTitle>
          <h1>Java</h1>
          <span>Há 1 dia</span>
        </CardTitle>
        <CardDescription>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores atque reiciendis voluptatum reprehenderit deserunt, velit ab vel aut provident voluptatibus iusto ipsum necessitatibus suscipit, veritatis rerum doloremque incidunt consequatur blanditiis?
        </CardDescription>
      </CardContent>
    </CardContainer>
  )
}
```

I need the text to occupy only the space of the div, without invading the padding, and when the text is larger than the space, it is necessary that the text be cut and added "..." to the end

example

[image: model success]

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

Reduce this container's padding or make it zero.

```
export const CardContent = styled.div`
  padding: 0; // 0 ||  1rem 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
  position: sticky ;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1.5rem;
`
```

Comment: if I remove the padding, the look of my application will be bad, until then the solution I found was to cut the text in JS, so as not to exceed the amount of characters. ````text.length > 150 && (text = `${text.substring(0,150)}...`)}````